# if $A_z$ and $B_z$ have zero content and $\int_{A_z}1=\int_{B_z}1$ for any $z$ then $\int_{A}1=\int_{B}1$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $ A,B\in \mathbb{R}^3$.For each $z\in \mathbb{R} $ we define $A_z=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 | (x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3\}$, similarly we define $B_z$.
Show that if $\partial A_z$ and $\partial B_z$ have zero content and $\int_{A_z}1=\int_{B_z}1$ for any $z$ then $\int_{A}1=\int_{B}1$

Proof:

Let $M,N$ intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $$ A  = A_z \times M \hspace{1cm} B =B_z \times N$$

It is easy to convince yourself that $\partial A$ and $\partial B$ has zero measure so that $ A, B $ are J-measurable, also if we define $f = 1$, it is bounded on $ A $ and $ B $, it is also continuous, that is, the set of discontinuities of $f$ is of measure zero, therefore $f$ is integrable over A and B, if we apply Fubbi
$$\int_Af=\int_{A_Z \times M}f=\int_{M\times A_Z}f =\int_{M}\int_{A_Z}f=\int_{M}\int_{B_Z}f$$
The last inequality is given by hypothesis, however I do not know how the following equality occurs
$$\int_{M}\int_{B_Z}f=\int_{N}\int_{B_Z}f=\int_B f$$
can someone help me?